# Dapper PostgreSQL composite type not supported

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

Considering a model

```
public record Model
(
  UserTimestamp A, 
  UserTimestamp B, 
  UserTimestamp[] C
)
```

with `UserTimestamp` being a composite type in postgresql `usertimestamp (int user_id, timestamp timestamp)`

and a .NET euqivalent
`public record UserTimestamp(int UserId, DateTime Timestamp)`

and it being mapped to npgsql via
`DataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<UserTimestamp>("usertimestamp");` in the repository

Dapper throws a `NotSupportedException` with message
`member "A" of type "Model" cannot be used as a parameter`

However, if i change the type to

```
public record Model
(
  UserTimestamp[] A, 
  UserTimestamp[] B, 
  UserTimestamp[] C
)
```

and change my db-table accordingly
and insert an array with the one element I tried inserting before it seems to work flawlessly.

Is there any reason behind not supporting a single composite type or am I missing something here?

Comment: You should probably post the use of `SqlMapper.AddTypeMap` as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
After some digging and trying to get this to work with NodaTime (as it is the recommended way of Npgsql)
I stumbled upon [this thread](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/198#issuecomment-699719732) where I discovered the `SqlMapper.AddTypeMap` method

So
`SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(UserTimestamp), DbType.Object);`

enables dapper to let Npgsql handle the type